# Alternative to RhodeCode for hosting Git repositories

Tags: collaboration, git

Up to now we have been using an old open source version of RhodeCode.

We use it to manage our git repos.

The new version of RhodeCode has a new [license](https://rhodecode.com/licenses), which is ... I don't know what to call it. It is open source, but only limited to 20 users. I don't get it.

We are less then 20 users, but a real open source solution would be preferred.

What we need:

- A web interface to browse git repos. (Browse commits, branches, ...)
- Editing the repo content via web interface is **not** needed.
- Pull/Push code via http with authentication and authorization
- We are about 10 developers and have about 100 repos.
- We only use git, no other source control software needs to be supported.
- Would be nice: full text search which spans severals git repos.
- Should be self hosted on linux.

**Update**

I guess we will use Kallithea. Related: http://sfconservancy.org/blog/2014/jul/15/why-kallithea/

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. To quickly summarize as it applies to this Q: list your requirements and preferences don't require people to research your previous solution. also What OS(es)?

Comment: I updated the question and added our needs.

Comment: @Caleb Their website claims they're open source..

Comment: @Seth And where exactly are they distributing the source code? Since it's a script you do end up with (most) of it, but I'm not even sure what they are doing is legal. They appear to be renigging on the GPLv3. They are trying to state that the code in GPLv3 but you can't run it even on your own servers to of you have more than X users. That's nonsense.

Comment: I would look at Perforce.  Free for up to 20 users with full support etc.  Resides on Linux (or Win) and works well with Git (from what I have read, we don't use it with Git, hence a comment and not an answer) www.perforce.com I will say the web client leaves a lot to be desired but the local client GUI is great.

Comment: @James an open source solution is preferred.

Comment: I noticed that, another reason it was a comment and not an answer.  Just wanted to throw the option out in case you can't find what you are looking for.  Call it a backup option.

Comment: [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/) is a new fork of RhodeCode -- it is made to deal with the license mess created by the original authors. I would migrate to that, especially if you're already happy with RhodeCode.

Comment: Kallithea is practically a dead project. And Python 2.x support runs out soon, whereas the Kallithea code base was never updated to run on Python 3.x ... as a fork Kallithea never seemed to gain the traction of other projects (or forks).

Comment: RhodeCode did a mistake with the licensing changes. But since then a lot changed. Project is actively developed and there's a limit free AGPL version available as RhodeCode Community edition. This is similar to GitLab with CE/EE versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best open-source git repository management tool that you can self-host that I know of is [**Gitlab**](http://gitlab.org/).

In is not a 100% drop in replacement to RhodeCode, but it does perform much the same role of managing repositories, users and their permissions on them.

It offers a wrapper around bare git repositories on a server giving you easy to manage SSH and HTTP/S access via git. You can manage your password or SSH keys from the user dashboard. There is a surprising degree of granular control over repositories even being able to limit who can push to specific branches.

In addition there are project management functions such as an integrated issue tracker or you can use hooks to integrate with various third party ones. Various workflows are supported including grouping repos, allowing users to make their own copies of repositories and submit merge requests back to the original.

Repositories can be in completely public space, shared with specific users, shared with a group  or completely private. The dashboard provides a surprisingly fast and useful view of code, commits and branches as well as issues, merges and a wiki. Quick hacks to edit a file and commit can be done from an inline editor right in the dashboard.

It might lack some of the enterprise polish and advertising that all those licensing dollars produce, but it's a quite effective repository manage.

Also see this answer focused [on alternatives to Github](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1008/429).