# Self-hosted code management software

Tags: web-apps, software-development, git

I need a recommendation for something similar to the existing post:

- the [Self-hosted replacement for Github thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/867/self-hosted-replacement-for-github/16163) and
- the [Self-hosted replacements for Mercurial thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/self-hosted-replacements-for-mercurial).

In the two aforementioned, I am finding the information a bit lacking to make a decision. And my aim is slightly different from the author of the thread above.

I need somethings that offers the following:

- Commercial support (obviously price is a big concern);
- Runs on Windows Server 2008 (or later) out of the box (no linux VM);
- Has features similar to github/gitlab in term of code repository management (repo management, code browsing, activity stream, user control, etc ...).
- Uses Git and/or Mercurial. Bonus for subversion hosting (legacy code) - only read write would be necessary through a web interface.

There is absolutely no concern for it being FOSS or not, as I do want commercial support for it.

What product can you recommend?

Thanks.

On a side note, I am finding myself compiling information onto a google sheet: [Self-hosted code management software](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zX_oj9SEFNyzl09AihuCX_U9g1d5aEWbKV4mOncMIT8/edit?usp=sharing). To help me making the decision as I could not see any matrix view of such a comparison with all the different visible options (I actually might have missed features in the list). And I think it could be useful for others.

Comment: I think you have missed off GForge AS and FusionForge to mention two that I am familiar with.

Comment: I also should point out that you are not actually asking a question so this is likely to be down voted &/or closed.  Maybe you should add a question element such as "What others should I be looking at"...

Comment: I'll change the formulation of the post first. I'll add those two to the sheet later (possibly tomorrow).

Comment: Is Git support required?

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about that; git OR mercurial required. I'll amend the post.

Answer (score 1):

[RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com) is the one I know about. The Community Edition is open source, but RhodeCode EE (Enterprise Edition) has commercial support ($75/user at the moment of writing), runs on Windows Server and has all the features you've mentioned, including pull requests and user management. In fact, their code review system is one of the best I ever worked with.

RhodeCode supports Git, SVN, and Mercurial and they have a nice, modern web interface:
[image: RhodeCode interface]