# Self-hosted replacement for Github for subversion

Tags: web-apps, software-development, subversion

I saw [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/867/self-hosted-replacement-for-github) popular questoin about a self-hosted replacement for GitHub...

However, only 2 of the answers (the low-vote ones) support subversion. While I'll definitely look into those particular two (Phabricator and Tuleap) I want to see if there's anything else out there.

We want basically the same features as the other OP, including (copy/pasted + edited):

1. Relatively good web UI: source code and commit browsing are a must.
2. Support for Subversion
3. SSH shell (repositories must be accessible over ssh, instead of just http)
4. Permissions: at least

   - private/public repositories
   - read-only and full access
   - Same permission set for web UI and for SSH (when granting/modifying permissions, it should be reflected to both)
5. Administration tools: creating repositories, granting access
6. Preferably search, including tickets, users, projects, filenames and inside source code
7. Preferably runs in Linux and windows

Comment: So support for Git is not needed, correct? // With "Preferably runs in Linux and windows", do you mean the server operating systems? Or the user operating systems? (but why would the user OS matter if it’s a web app?)

Comment: Correct - git support not necessary. Runs in windows/linux because we currently have all windows servers but are migrating to linux. We'd like to implement the software ASAP, likely before the migration is complete. However, it *could* be the first thing to be 'migrated' to linux if necessary

Answer (score 2):

I saw you already referenced [Tuleap](http://tuleap.org) from the previous recommendation.

For lazy readers, I'll reword it here:

1. Good web UI: we are on a big UI overhaul and our [screenshot gallery](http://www.tuleap.org/about-tuleap/screenshot-gallery) speaks for us. For the subversion part, we rely on viewvc + our commit tracking base.
2. Subversion is supported. One repository per workspace/project, you can create as much project you need.
3. No SSH, HTTP(S) only
4. Permissions are fully under your control as a project administrator per path bases. We recently introduced an [Access control trail](http://www.tuleap.org/releases/7.1/release-notes.html) to keep track of changes in permissions.

   - Permissions apply on the web interface and at sources level
5. administration is 100% web, allows to define notifications, per branch and various hooks (no empty messages, jenkins hook).
6. Elasticsearch powerd search for documentation system and Tracker/ticket (under development). No search in source code yet
7. Open Source (GPLv2) and runs on Linux only (RHEL6 like)

Comes with Tuleap Trackers (think Tuleap Trackers like ticket under steroid) for all project management needs, Agile Dashboard, [native Eclipse integration](http://www.tuleap.org/eclipse-connector-tuleap-21-available-now-supports-agile-processes), even for the Agile thing, documentation, Git, mailing lists, ...

The nice part is that all theses are playing nicely together out of the box: reference svn commits in your tickets and the reverse, or with the documentation, in an instance messaging chat room. You get the full tracability of your devs.

Give it a try on the [demo site](https://demo-tuleap.enalean.com/).

Disclaimer: I'm core developer of the product.

[image: Tuleap SVN interface]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to take a closer look at [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/). VisualSVN Server is not a webapp, it is a fully-fledged Subversion server package for Active Directory environment.

> 1. Relatively good web UI: source code and commit browsing are a must.

VisualSVN Server has a modern web interface for Subversion repos. The web interface

- features a revision history browser,
- shows inline differences for modified files,
- supports syntax highlighting for common programming languages,
- supports rendering markdown files,
  etc.

  [**See the live demo here**](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#).

[image: VisualSVN Server web interface changeset view]

> 2. Support for Subversion

VisualSVN Server is a Subversion server package, it supports Apache Subversion only.

> 3. SSH shell (repositories must be accessible over ssh, instead of just http)

Repositories are accessible via HTTP(S) only.

> 4. Permissions: at least
>
>    - private/public repositories
>    - read-only and full access
>    - Same permission set for web UI and for SSH (when granting/modifying permissions, it should be reflected to both)

VisualSVN Server supports granular authorization and provides a graphical interface to manage access rules remotely or locally. You can manage access rules using

1. [VisualSVN Server Manager (administrator's console)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/remote-admin/)

[image: VisualSVN Server Manager console]

2. [VisualSVN Repository Configurator tool (manager's console)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/)

[image: VisualSVN Repository Configurator]

> 5. Administration tools: creating repositories, granting access

VisualSVN Server Manager and VisualSVN Repository Configurator tools allow you to administer the server and manage the repositories through a familiar Microsoft Management Console (MMC) interface.

> 6. Preferably search, including tickets, users, projects, filenames and inside source code

Full-text repository search is not yet available.

> 7. Preferably runs in Linux and windows

VisualSVN Server runs on Windows only, however it is accessible by any HTTP(S)-capable Subversion client.

Answer (score 1):

**RhodeCode Enterprise 3 (https://rhodecode.com) meets ALL of your  requirements:**

1. Relatively good web UI: YES
2. Support for Subversion: YES, even supports Git & Mercurial
3. SSH shell: YES, possible with plugin
4. Permissions: YES, full enterprise-grade permission system with permission delegation, permission groups, inheritance, LDAP/AD support, etc.
5. Administration tools: YES
6. Preferably search: YES, complete search over everything
7. Preferably runs in Linux: YES, runs even under Windows

RhodeCode Enterprise is free for 10 users, NGOs and EDUs. It is written in Python, used in production at 10,000+ organizations and was hardened and tuned by these organizations over more than 3 years.

Disclaimer: I am a RhodeCode co-founder.