# Git web frontend hostgator shared hosting

Tags: git, web-server

I have GIT up and running on my shared hosting account from host gator but I would like to have a nice frontend like GitHub.com. I found tons of options but everything that seems to be maintained is written in a language that requires a high level of hosting (dedicated) to install it on the server.

If the UI is not possible what about something like gerrit for code review?

Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Have you seen [Self-hosted replacement for Github](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/867/185)?